# CNContactPickerViewController [CNUI ERROR] error calling service - Couldn’t communicate with a helper application

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using below code to let the user select contacts from their saved contacts:

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI

class AddGroupViewController:UIViewController{


  var contacts:[Contact] = []
  var selectecPhoneBookContacts:[String] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {

  }

  @IBAction func selectPhoneBook(_ sender: Any) {
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [
      CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey
    ]
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    if !selectecPhoneBookContacts.isEmpty{
      contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = CNContact.predicateForContacts(withIdentifiers: selectecPhoneBookContacts)
    }
    self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}

extension AddGroupViewController:CNContactPickerDelegate{
  func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
    for contact in contacts{
      selectecPhoneBookContacts.append(contact.identifier)
    }
  }
}
```

The first time it works perfectly. But the second time, when this code is executed

```
if !selectecPhoneBookContacts.isEmpty{
      contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = CNContact.predicateForContacts(withIdentifiers: selectecPhoneBookContacts)
    }
```

I end up in errors:

```
2017-02-03 09:23:37.501 SmartList[57062:10996092] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
2017-02-03 09:23:37.504 SmartList[57062:10996203] [CNUI ERROR] error calling service - Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.
2017-02-03 09:23:47.479 SmartList[57062:10996092] [CNUI ERROR] Contact picker delayed appearance timed out - YES
2017-02-03 09:23:57.480 SmartList[57062:10996092] [CNUI ERROR] Contact picker delayed appearance timed out - YES
```

What I wanted to is: let the user only select a contact once. If the contact is selected once, it can't be added a second time

Comment: Hope it helps! https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/223/.   All of the needed information you can find from this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using my own NSPredicate:

```
if !selectecPhoneBookContacts.isEmpty{
  contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "NOT(identifier IN %@)", selectecPhoneBookContacts)
}
```